# Retrieving variables with the same name as a string

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a bunch of maps inside a class and I would like to make a generic method to retreive the specific map that matches the ID.
Something like:

```
private Map map1;
private Map map2;
private Map map3;


public Map getMap(String id){
  return mapX;
}
```

And when I call the method as:

```
getMap("map1");
```

It will return map1.
Any way I can do this conversion whithout creating a map of maps?

Comment: Use factory design pattern

Comment: Store them in a `Map[]` array and retrieve them by index?

Comment: not sure if that is so wise to do, why should the *external* code know about the names used internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use reflection, for example:

```
    private Map getMap(String id) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        getClass().getField("map" + id).get(this);
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: You bet me to this answer - but just one thing here, you've changed the access of getMap to private. In the question it's public, and in order to make it public it might be necessary to call setAccessible(true) on the Field.

Answer (score 2):

Map of map can be also the solution for this :

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("map1", map1); 
    map.put("map2", map2);

public static Map<String, String> getMap(String name){
   return map.get(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define a Map of String, Map and use it as dictionary

like:

```
private Map map1;
private Map map2;
private Map map3;
private Map<String, Map> mapX;

public Map getMap(String id) {
    return this.mapX.getOrDefault(id, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having only few numbers of map then you can use the switch statement and retuen the map which matches the map name like below code :-

```
switch (mapName) {
            case "map1":
                return map1;
            break;
            case "map2":
                return map2;
            break;
        }
```

But if you have large number of Maps then its better to give some id or name to them and use Map of Map.

Comment: Not really a few. This is a property class read from a json file with Gson. Every map has configuration informations for something. So I might have hundreds of maps.

Comment: @AlexanderRumanovsk , then as i suggested its better to use Map of Map , where key would be the id or name of Map, which you want to return.